# Is it possible to increase horizontal and vertical padding on ffmpeg burned subtitles - using .srt format?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, .srt

Using command :

```
ffmpeg -i source_video_path.mp4 -vf "subtitles=srt_source.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=4,BackColour=&H80000000,Outline=0,Shadow=0,MarginV=25,Fontname=Arial,Fontsize=10,Alignment=2'" video_destination.mp4
```

I get

[image]

Ideally I would like to increase the subtitles background padding - especially horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase value of shadow, like `"Shadow=10"` and you will add padding to your BG.

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870169/how-to-set-background-to-subtitle-in-ffmpeg) you can read more about this.

As I know, no way to change x,y axis separately for BG size.